# Phpmyadmin Not able to Search or Insert

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Whenever I go to Phpmyadmin and try to search in a DB. It takes me back to the home page of  Phpmyadmin i.e; hxxp://xxxxx.com/phpmyadmin without any error. Same happens when I try to insert something in the DB. I am using Ubuntu and have installed Phpmyadmin using apt-get. I tried Removing and Reinstalling it several times but I still get the same error. Can you please help me solve it.

PS : I just figured its happening incase of only one Database. Its working Fine for others.

Comment: If you export the structure of that database and try to import it to the demo server at http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/ are you able to reproduce the problem? (Feel free to obscure any sensitive information).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the web server's error log for hints about any failures.

Comment: Could you tell me where can I find it ? Thanks. There are many files here : /var/log

Comment: Its happening on in case of one database. Working fine for others.

Comment: For the error log, look on Google for "Ubuntu web server error log". About your database, anything special in it (number of tables?). By the way, which phpMyAdmin version is this?

Comment: Well, Its weird as in some of the tables in the database its working and for some it isnt working. No Errors related to Database in logs.

PhpMyadmin Version information: 3.4.10.1deb1
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
MySQL client version: 5.5.32
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation